# How to solve CSS -webkit-appearance issue

Tags: html, css

I have CSS from bootstrap that I need to override to get it back to its default browser appearance

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Here is a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wgLokucd/

How would I get rid of this so the styling is just as it would be if I had no CSS applied to:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than easy: Disable the style in your fiddle in Chrome’s dev tools, look at the *computed styles*, and find that

```
-webkit-appearance: push-button;
```

gets applied via the user agent stylesheet …

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This is the correct answer, not `button`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give back the default value of the element you are styling.

Check this list of the possible **-webkit-appearance values**:

```
checkbox
radio
push-button
square-button
button
button-bevel
listbox
listitem
menulist
menulist-button
menulist-text
menulist-textfield
scrollbarbutton-up
scrollbarbutton-down
scrollbarbutton-left
scrollbarbutton-right
scrollbartrack-horizontal
scrollbartrack-vertical
scrollbarthumb-horizontal
scrollbarthumb-vertical
scrollbargripper-horizontal
scrollbargripper-vertical
slider-horizontal
slider-vertical
sliderthumb-horizontal
sliderthumb-vertical
caret
searchfield
searchfield-decoration
searchfield-results-decoration
searchfield-results-button
searchfield-cancel-button
textfield
textarea
```

**CSS**

```
 input{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    input {
        -webkit-appearance: button;
    }
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/wgLokucd/2/